# AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'label'

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()
win.geometry("640x320")
win.title("e")
text1 = tk.label('yes', width = '200', height = '100', text = 'testing')
text1.pack()
win.mainloop()
```

So basically I've been starting to learn tkinter but it keeps giving me this error what do I do?

Comment: It should be `tk.Label(...)` instead, capital L.  Don't import tkinter like your code, just use `import tkinter as tk` and remove `from tkinter import *`.  Also you need to change the first argument `'yes'` to `win`.